# How can we make __future__ imports global?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Specs: Python 2.7

I'm working on a project that has several modules, I want to activate some features from the __future__ module in all of them. I would like to import all the features I need on one module, and then import that single module to every other, and have those features be active in all of them, or something to that effect.

I tried:

*[A.py]*

```
from __future__ import division
```

*[B.py]*

```
import A
print(1/2)
```

Running B.py the division was still integer. I tried:

*[A.py]*

```
print(1/2)
```

*[B.py]*

```
from __future__ import division
import A
```

Running B.py gave the same result. With both previous examples I also tried switching 'import A' by 'from A import *' with the same results.

I searched Google for a while, and found the best description about how the __future__ module works, obviously enough, on the Python documentation. There I could only find the assurance the features would be active in the module they were imported to, without any mention of how to do it globally.

So I'd like to know if there is a way of doing this, either the way I described, or creating some sort of runtime configuration file, or through some other means.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's no way to do this in-language; you really can't make `__future__` imports global in this sense. (Well, you probably can replace the normal `import` statements with something complicated around `imp` or something. See the [Future statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#future) documentation and scroll down to "Code compiled by…" But anything like this is almost certainly a bad idea.)

The reason is that `from __future__ import division` isn't really a normal import. Or, rather, it's *more than* a normal import. You actually *do* get a name called `division` that you can inspect, but just having that value has no effect—so passing it to other modules doesn't affect those modules. On top of the normal import, Python has special magic that detects `__future__` imports at the top of a module, or in the interactive interpreter, and changes the way your code is compiled. See [**future**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html) for the "real import" part, and [Future statements](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#future) for the "magic" part, if you want all the details.

And there's no configuration file that lets you do this. But there is a command-line parameter:

```
python -Qnew main.py
```

This has the same effect as doing a `from __future__ import division` everywhere.

You can add this to the `#!` lines, or `alias pyfuturediv='python -Qnew'` (or even `alias python='python -Qnew'`) in your shell, or whatever, which maybe as good as a configuration file for your purposes.

But really, if you want to make sure module B gets new-style division, you probably *should* have the `__future__` declaration in B in the first place.

Or, of course, you could just write for Python 3.0+ instead of 2.3-2.7. (Note that some of the core devs were against having command-line arguments, because "the right way to get feature X globally is to use a version of Python >= feature X's MandatoryRelease".) Or use `//` when you mean `//`.

Another possibility is to use [six](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/six), a module designed to let you write code that's almost Python 3.3 and have it work properly in 2.4-2.7 (and 3.0-3.2). For example, you don't get a `print` function, but you do get a `print_` function that works exactly the same. You don't get Unicode literals, but you get `u()` fake literals—which, together with a UTF-8 encoding declaration in the source, is almost good enough. And it provides a whole lot of stuff that you can't get from `__future__` as well—`StringIO` and `BytesIO`, `exec` as a function, the `next` function, etc.

If the problem is that you have 1000 source files, and it's a pain to edit them all, you could use `sed`, or use `3to2` with just the option that fixes division, or…

Comment: +1 -- the key point being that `from __future__ import [foo]` isn't an import statement at all; it's a [future statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#future-statements) that has effects at compile time.

Comment: @senderle: Good point; I'll rewrite things to make that clearer. Although it actually _is_ an import statement, it's not _just_ an import statement. The docs define exactly what `foo` will get bound to by that statement.

Comment: I don't control the system the application is to be released on, so Python 3.x is off the table.  I don't plan to include just division, that was just an example, I plan to include all four relevant to 2.7.  I don't have a huge amount of files to change, I could do it by hand. I'm just trying to make it less error prone for future releases, and prettier. ^_^  I wouldn't want to keep adding those lines to every module I happen to create, and several others are expected to be created. I might go with the command line option if it covers all features.

Comment: @xor: There's `division`, `print_function`, and `unicode_literals`… what's the fourth? Anyway, really, if you want to write Python 3 code but have it run in 2.7, there are probably better ways to do it, like running `3to2` (even automatically in your `setup.py`), or using the `six` library. Or put in the explicit `__future__` statements—seriously, a later maintainer (or you, a year from now) will be confused by, e.g., print functions in 2.7 code, unless there's some kind of explicit indication of what's going on—which is part of the reason `__future__` imports are ugly and must be at the top.

Comment: @abarnert: It only covers unicode_literals and division, too bad. The fourth should be absolute_import. I guess explicit is better than implicit, I just wish it could so without being so repetitive.

Comment: @xor: See my edited answer; I think the `six` module may actually be exactly what you want here. Meanwhile, you don't need `absolute_import` because 2.7 already has that on by default, just like 3.x. (You're allowed to specify it anyway, of course, which is handy if you want your code to run on 2.6 as well…)

Comment: @abarnert: Could you share where you read that 2.7 already has absolute_import by default? The documentation I read stated differently. http://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html#module-__future__

Comment: absolute_import is not enabled in Python 2 (it would break backward-compatibility) e.g., if you have os.py file in your_package then `import os` inside the package will overshadow stdlib's os module if you run a script in the same directory (to fix it use top-level scripts).

Comment: @xor: Try `__future__.absolute_import.mandatory` in a 2.7 interpreter. Also see [PEP 328](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#rationale-for-absolute-imports) itself (which says that it's optional in 2.5 and 2.6), and [what's new](http://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-328-absolute-and-relative-imports). 2.7 doesn't have the feature in the exact same way as 3.x, but it does have the 2.x absolute behavior on by default, unlike 2.5-2.6.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: See my comment to xor. It is confusing that the import  behavior in 2.7 is neither the same as up to 2.6, or the same as in 3.x, but it's true.

Comment: @abarnert: [2.7 *does not* have it on](http://bugs.python.org/issue14494) (just try it).

Answer (score 3):

Another approach would be using [isort](https://github.com/timothycrosley/isort). `isort` has a `-a` command line flag to add imports to files that you specify. Simply running `isort` without arguments will run it recursively on all python files in the current working directory and all subdirectories.

If, like me, you have a virtual environment inside that folder, and are using git (or have an equivalent way of listing only your files) and don't want to run it on all files inside that virtual environment, you can use something like:

`git ls-tree -r HEAD --name-only | grep "\.py$" | xargs isort -a -y "from __future__ import division"`