# Import absolute import only once in Django project

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I like to use `absolute_import` function in  Python 2.7. Because in Python 2.7 there is no `absolute_import`
So I have to import it like this.

`from __future__ import absolute_import`

In my Django project I have a lot of files, like `models.py, views.py` and so on. And on top of each file I have to put

`from __future__ import absolute_import`

to be able to use this function.

Question is following:
If there is possibility to import `absolute_import` only once in project and use it everywhere ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "import only once"? Python only imports a module once unless you explicitly `reload()` it or use some other fancy import function.

Comment: But why do you need it in each package? In most cases there is no difference whether you use one mode or the other. This becomes relevant only if you have an ambiguity.

Comment: I have Django project and I would like to use absolute_import in every file e.g `views.py`, `forms.py`, etc. of each module in project

Comment: This is a strange question. Absolute imports *are* a part of Python 2.7 -- this `__future__` import should only be needed for Python 2.6 or lower (see [PEP328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/)). The symbol you are importing, `absolute_import`, is useless (and it's not a function even, it's a class). Are you in fact using Python 2.6 and want `absolute_import` semantics without having to explicitly "activate" it in every file? You can't really do that, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773861/how-can-we-make-future-imports-global for example.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with frequent use of `absolute_import` is usually caused by the ambiguity within a package. If you are developing several subpackages and need to constantly use `absolute_import` to use a top-level package, just rename the problem subpackage. It is anyway a good idea.

Comment: nice I totally did not understand what he was talking about

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to redefine [`__import__` built-in function](//docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__), which is invoked by `import` statements. This can be used to emulate the behavior of `absolute_import`. You need to do this *before* you import anything:

```
# This function will replace __builtin__.__import__.
# By default, the fifth argument (level) is not supplied.
# We use the value 0, which means absolute import.
def new_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level=0):
    # Call the original function.
    return orig_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)

import __builtin__
# Save a reference to the original function.
orig_import = __builtin__.__import__
# Replace it with the new one.
__builtin__.__import__ = new_import
```

Now, all `import` statements anywhere in the program will call this function, which will make them perform absolute imports, unless they explicitly use relative-import syntax.